# Mongodb/Mongoose: Filling Array of ObjectIds (references)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb running (MEAN environment) with two collections (users and books). One of those collections (myusers) contains an array of Objectids (references to documents of books collection) as such:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    [...],
    externalids: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Books', required: false}]
    }, {collection: 'myusers'});
```

At runtime, I'd like to constantly fill that array (externalids) with ids of new book documents. This is how I do it:

```
var newBook = new Book({ ... });

        newBook.save(function (err){
                if (err){
                    //whatever  
                }else{
                    User.update({ _id: req.user._id }, { $set: { externalids: newBook._id }}, function(err){
                        //whatever       
                    });
                }
        });
```

Unfortunately, I can't use something like:

```
externalids: externalids.push(newBook._id)
```

I even tried:

```
User.update({ _id: req.user._id }, { $push: { externalids: newBook._id }}
```

But it wouldn't help either.
Thus, the array always only contains one value (the latest) and won't be filled up. Is there a quick way to append more values? Would be nice if there was a quicker way than reading the array content first, storing it to a local temporary array, append the new value and write the entire array back...
Cheers

Igor

Comment: Even when using $push you still only get one item in the array?

Comment: No, using $push does not change anything!? Doesn't even alter the single item...

Comment: is newBook._id an ObjectId or a string representation?

Comment: That `$push` statement is how you do this.  Make sure you provide a callback to `update` and check for errors.

Comment: According to robomongo, the stored item in the document is an ObjectId("5424...").

Comment: After logging the mongoerror, I now know what the problem is. MongoError: The field 'externalids' must be an array but is of type OID in document {_id: ObjectId('541...')}. Strange, I thought, I declared it correctly (=as an array of objectids)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $addToSet instead of $push to avoid duplicate id.

```
User.update({ _id: req.user._id }, { $addToSet : { externalids: newBook._id }}
```

What can be your issue is that you previously use `$set` to update an user. This will initially create externalids as string, not array, hence you cannot use  `$push/$addToSet` on externalids afterwards. To correct that, try to update your user externalids as an array first:

```
User.update({ _id: req.user._id }, { $set : { externalids: [] }}
```

Comment: Thanks! You were right. As I used $set in the meantime, the type of the externalids field was sort of casted to OID and thus could not be pushed any more. After deleting the user document and creating a new one (and now using $push or $addToSet), it works just fine.